# Resize scene when opening & closing TitledPane

Tags: javafx

I was wondering, how I can resize `Scene`, when expanding & collapsing `TitledPane`.

I had tried case with only 1 `TitledPane`

### 1 TitledPane

```
package fxinswing;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXInSwing extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

        TitledPane tp = new TitledPane();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        grid.add(new Label("First Name: "), 0, 0);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Last Name: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Email: "), 0, 2);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);        
        tp.setText("Grid 1");
        tp.setContent(grid);

        stage.setTitle("TitledPane");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

        Group root = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        root.getChildren().add(tp);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting during closing

[image]

and Here's what I'm expecting during opening

[image]

However, currently, when it is opening or closing, it always stay the same way (Except the direction of arrow)

[image]

I was wondering, how can I pack my `Scene`'s size changed accordingly, so that it will always "fit" to the actual size of `TitledPane`, during opening & closing.

### Update:

@James_D proposed a great way to overcome 1 `TitledPane` case.

However, when using 2 `TitledPane`s

### 2 TitledPanes

```
package fxinswing;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXInSwing extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("TitledPane");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new GridPane());
        scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

        final GridPane  root = (GridPane )scene.getRoot();

        TitledPane tp = new TitledPane();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(4);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        grid.add(new Label("First Name: "), 0, 0);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Last Name: "), 0, 1);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
        grid.add(new Label("Email: "), 0, 2);
        grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);        
        tp.setText("Grid 1");
        tp.setContent(grid);

        tp.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
                stage.sizeToScene();
            }

        });

        TitledPane tp2 = new TitledPane();

        GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
        grid2.setVgap(4);
        grid2.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        grid2.add(new Label("First Name: "), 0, 0);
        grid2.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
        grid2.add(new Label("Last Name: "), 0, 1);
        grid2.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
        grid2.add(new Label("Email: "), 0, 2);
        grid2.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);        
        tp2.setText("Grid 2");
        tp2.setContent(grid2);


        tp2.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
                stage.sizeToScene();
            }            
        });

        root.add(tp, 0, 0);
        root.add(tp2, 0, 1);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

The outcome looks like following. The `Scene` will never resize, doesn't matter you are opening or closing the `TitledPane`s.

I don't use `Accordion`, as I want two `TitledPane`s to be independent from each others.

I had try

```
root.requestLayout();
```

But, still, nothing has changed. Any idea how I can make 2 `TitledPane`s work?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    tp.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldHeight, newHeight) -> stage.sizeToScene());
```

Comment: Hi James_D, thanks. That's work very well for 1 TitledPane case. In my real app, I need to use 2 TitledPane instead of 1. I prevent from using Accordion, as the opening & closing of 2 TitledPanes, are independent from each others. If I use `Group` in `Scene`, it seems that 2 `TitledPanes` will stack together. I try again with `GridPane` in `Scene`, the resizing no longer work, even I had added `GridPane.requestLayout` in listener. Do you mind I can refine my question, with more details on case when TitledPane is 2?

Comment: You could register the same listener with both titled panes

Comment: Hi @James_D, I had tried various ways but it doesn't work still. Would you kindly take a look & provide your precious comment? Thanks.

Comment: Your code for 2 titled panes works, as long as you fix the bug `tp2.setContent(grid2);` (not `grid`).

Comment: Opps. What a shame. But, after I fix to `tp2.setContent(grid2)`, it still stay the same. Does it work at your side? Is it because I'm using Java 7 & not Java 8?

Comment: Yes, I can only get it to work in Java 8. In Java 7, it works (though not very well) if you also add a listener to the `TitledPane`s' `expandedProperty`s, calling `stage.sizeToScene()` when they change. You need to make sure the stage is initialized to be big enough. It's a bit unreliable still.